# Rx: Auto-refreshing list(array)

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, observablecollection

I want to implement observable of array that auto-refresh itself. I do it like this:

```
const list$ = Observable.create(function(observer) {
  getList(list => observer.next(threads);
}));

const liveList$ = Observable.interval(2000).switchMapTo(list$);
```

When I do `subscribe` to the `liveList$` stream I get values only after `n` ms. as expected.

The question is how can I get values after first call of `getList` immediately and each next call with interval?

P.S. I've tried to `$list.switchMapTo($liveList).subscribe(console.log)` but nothing is changed in behaviour of the chain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`timer`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-timer) operator instead. It can be passed an initial delay, as well as a period:

```
Observable.timer(0, 2000).switchMapTo(list$);
```